# Additional map source information for Willmore Wilderness Park in Alberta?

Tags: maps, trails

I currently have the Canada NTS 1:50,000 maps, and the 1990 revision of the complete park map.  They don't agree on details, and so far the NTS maps have higher error rates.

I also have a couple of publications of Alberta Parks that contain less info.

I have inquired with the Willmore Wilderness Foundation.

I have found ray's website which has trails for the Eagle's Nest Pass area including several that are not marked on any of the others.  I've verified several.

I am specifically looking to access the Resthaven Icefield from the Willmore side, preferably connected to it from Rock Lake.  I have trails as far as part way up West Sulfur River from two sources, and further up toward a pass that goes over the Jasper park boundary to Azure lake.

It looks like it should be possible to go over the saddle to the west of the turn to Azure Lake to get into the next valley onto Rock Slide Creek.  From there, getting to Ptarmigan Lake near the Jackpine River looks, hmm, non-obvious.

Anyone done anything in this corner of Willmore?